# Radio show where only drunks can see goblins

Tags: story-identification, radio-play

Years ago I heard an old SF/Fantasy radio anthology program where an alcoholic is recruited by the FBI to fight goblins (or kobolds or some underground fantasy race).

The goblins are invisible to sober humans but, with enough booze, they're perceptible. The FBI recruiter comments:

> I wish we had men who could drink like you.

At one point the drunken protagonist gets a goblin-sized invisibility cloak that couldn't cover his whole body, leaving his head visible. When a goblin spots him, he sings "I ain't got no body" and scares it off (I have to assume this was before Young Frankenstein).

I thought the name of the episode was "My cup floweth over" and was on X Minus One but episode guides don't list it.

I believe I heard it on WVXU 91.7 in Cincinnati in the 1990s.

Comment: Welcome to SFF! Could you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337) and see if there is anything else you can [edit] in? For example, you say you heard it years ago, when was that?

Comment: Might the name have been something like "My cup *runneth* over"?  That's the famous phrasing of Psalm 23 in the King James Version.

Comment: It could have been "My Cup Runneth Over." There's not an X Minus One episode by that name but it's a hope.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is an episode from the mid-eighties radio show *Midnight*. The title of that episode is indeed "My Cup Runneth Over".  The show is exactly as you remember it.  You can listen to it (and many other episodes of *Midnight*) [here](http://www.fearyoucanhear.com/shows/andromedacbsrmt.php?q=f&f=%2FMidnight).